# Cannot find name defined in same file; How to achieve union type of const values?

Tags: typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I export some string constants and try to use them for a type definition in the same file, and it doesn't work.

```js
export const SET_DETERMINATION = 'SET_DETERMINATION';
export const SET_HIGHLIGHTING = 'SET_HIGHLIGHTING';
export const SET_TEXT = 'SET_TEXT';

export type THypoAction =
  SET_DETERMINATION
  | SET_HIGHLIGHTING
  | SET_TEXT;
```

> TS2304: Cannot find name 'SET_DETERMINATION'.
>
> TS2304: Cannot find name 'SET_HIGHLIGHTING'.
>
> TS2304: Cannot find name 'SET_TEXT'.

I can fix this by defining my type using the string values themselves, i.e.

```js
export type THypoAction =
  'SET_DETERMINATION'
  | 'SET_HIGHLIGHTING'
  | 'SET_TEXT';
```

But this seems more fragile than referencing the constants.

Is there any way of going about this where I achieve the following?

1. Declare the literal string values only once
2. Export the constants with their string values
3. Define a union type of the constants' string values

For context, I am looking to build a reducer which will accept dispatched actions that adhere to an interface like the following (only with a more specific payload)

```js
export interface IHypoAction {
  type: THypoAction;
  payload?: any;
}
```

In modules referencing this I thus need both the constants, and their type definition for the interface.

Comment: Try `export const SET_DETERMINATION: 'SET_DETERMINATION' = 'SET_DETERMINATION';`, etc.

Comment: Even with this, defining the type with `SET_DETERMINATION` still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are looking for: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/15486

It will be available in 2.4.

The problem you have is that `const X` is a value, not a type. Thus you can't use it in `type THypoAction = ...` which accepts types.

Comment: Plus it's already in the nightly build, so with `yarn add typescript@next --dev` we can use this already. Thanks

Comment: ... but Angular CLI 1.0.4 only supports TypeScript ~2.3.1, so for that we still have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

@unional I'm using ts 2.6.1 and it doesn't work. In the following code example ts cannot find the name 'SET_TOKEN', but this is fixed if I enclose it as string `readonly type: 'SET_TOKEN';`:

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';

export const SIGNUP = 'SIGNUP';
export const SIGNIN = 'SIGNIN';
export const LOGOUT = 'LOGOUT';
export const SET_TOKEN = 'SET_TOKEN';

/* Some other classes here */

export class SetToken implements Action {
    readonly type: SET_TOKEN; // ts error here. ts cannot find name
    constructor(public payload: string) { }
}

export type AuthActions =
    SignUp |
    SignIn |
    LogOut |
    SetToken;
```